# handle an input field under a transparent image

Tags: css, input, field

i have an transparent overlay and an input field under it. I have also buttons under this overlay.
To make the buttons work i write pointer-events:none as an css attribute at the overlay.

Are there an similar command to make input fields work?

Answer (score 3):

Pointer events:none does not work cross browser. I would suggest finding a way to bring the inputs to the top of the page. Perhaps the attribute

```
z-index:10; /*You also need to use position:relative; for this to take effect*/
```

would better suit the job?

I can also expand on my answer if you could post a link to where you are doing development on this.

Thanks

Comment: i use html 5 elements, so only the newer browsers can handle my script. I tested all this new browsers and everyone of them supports the pointer:none event.   I tried also with z-index but it didnt worked, cant figure out why..

Comment: Is it possible to post a link? Im more than happy to take a look and give some advice

Comment: thanks for the answere. unfortunately its not possible to link it because its a company - intern document. I just found out that javascript is disabling the field anyhow but ive got no idea how this can be happen.